# Is Did + second form correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

If I say, "How did she knew about it?" Would it be correct? If you use search engine for "did knew", you get hundred thousand results. Are they incorrect? I'm confused about this grammar structure.

Comment: "did knew" can show up in grammatical English sentences. For example, *"Most people refused to talk about it, and those who did knew little."* Most of the search results in Google books are of this form.

Comment: @RegDwight ΒВBẞ8: My last question was deleted immediately before I could read the comments. Can you let me know what they were?

Comment: @PeterShor: Can you please provide me a reference to the usage?

Comment: The above sentence means *"Most people refused to talk about it, and those (people) who did (talk about) it knew little (about it)."* That is, there is a noun phrase *"those who did"* followed by the past tense verb *"knew"*. So here, the verb *"did"* comes from *"did talk"* by [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), and is unconnected to the verb *"knew"*. Don't rely upon counts from search engines without checking them carefully.

Comment: @PeterShor: Why does "How did she knew about it?" isn't acceptable or why doesn't it sound right? I know its because the grammar rules but I don't understand it in practice. Can you throw some light on this please?

Comment: It's because people have internal grammar rules, and things that don't obey them sound wrong. This holds for all languages, including whichever one you grew up speaking. For English, this particular phrase sounds wrong because *did* always takes the uninflected form of the verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is incorrect. The sentence should read "***How did she know*** *about it?*", although probably the sentence "*How did she* ***get to know*** *about it*?" would sound more natural.

I think you should look the structure up in a common grammar book.

Comment: What about "How did that women knew about him"? is it still not right?

Comment: No, this sentence is almost the same as your original one - it isn't correct either. In questions main verbs are used as infinitives without to (know, not knew).